# AFrame v4 : TypeError: t.parentEl is null

Tags: aframe

I'm using the delete method that is explained in the doc of AFrame in "Using JavaScript and DOM APIs".

I created boxes that are attached to an entity that is defined in my scene.

```
var parent = document.getElementById('box');
      var entityEl = document.createElement('a-box');
      parent.appendChild(entityEl);
```

Then, to delete it i store each entityEl I have created in an array that is previously defined as an empty array.

```
entityEl.setAttribute('position', {x: x1*5, y: y1*5, z: z1*5});
  entityEl.setAttribute('material', 'color', 'blue');
  listPoint.push(entityEl);
```

The last step is to delete some of these boxes. So I use

```
function destroyPoint(point){

  listPoint.pop(point);
  if(point.parentNode != null){
    point.parentNode.removeChild(point);
  }

}
```

Everything looks fine but there is still a weird error in my console that i don't understand : "TypeError: t.parentEl is null" in "aframe.min.js:137:3912"
It doesn't look like an issue, but it's quite weird so i would like to know if someone can explain what is it. 
Thank you !

Comment: Is it possible you're trying to remove the entity before the entity has been fully initialized?